# Revisiting the choice of tungsten in light bulbs

Tags: thermodynamics, visible-light, electricity, electrical-resistance, thermal-conductivity

I admit questions around why tungsten is used in light bulb tend to be very common, but hopefully what I'm asking here is not a duplicate.

I am trying to understand which properties of tungsten make it a good choice for a light emitting metal to be used in bulbs, more preceisely:

- Is tungsten a good choice because it has a high heat conductivity, or high heat capacity, or low electrical conductivity (thus high resistance), or a combination of all three former factors?
- Formulated differently, what properties do we want the metal to have to qualify as a good light emitter in a bulb?

Ultimately, I'm interested in *how to reason* about this, i.e., given that we want this object to emit light with low energy consumption (low currents), what properties are of utmost importance. Once I understand how to think about this, I hope to be able to e.g. apply that understanding to various common other contexts, namely, what property do we want laptop surfaces to have? Some builds use aluminium, some use plastic-type of material, but at the end, what we want to achieve for a laptop is, the ability to dissipate heat quickly and not overheat the body and the hardware. Thus, in that view, what properties are key for the material we are going to use?

Comment: I assumed it was mostly because of tungsten's unusually high melting point.  At 2500 C copper, iron or aluminum would all be puddles at the bottom of the bulb.

Comment: Yes, I think that tungsten was chosen primarily because of its very high melting temperature. Don't think that thermal conductivity or heat capacity are significant factors. As for electrical conductivity, tungsten actually has a fairly high electrical conductivity and there are  only a few elemental metals that have a higher conductivity (Ag, Cu, Au, Al, and Ca), although the electrical conductivity of tungsten is a lot less at the normal filament operating temperature of a light bulb.

Comment: Note also that a high melting temperature is fundamentally correlated with a low vapor pressure (both trends result from strong atomic bonds). This low vapor pressure, along with an inert gas inside the bulb, is what prevents the filament from evaporating and blackening the inside of the bulb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main factors are

1. High [electrical resistivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity) compared to Cu, Ag and Au (otherwise you need a high potential difference to get the same current, from $I=V/R$).
2. Highest [melting temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melting_points_of_the_elements_(data_page)) of all metals, which is desirable for obvious reasons (as pointed out by [M. Enns](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/112507/m-enns) in the comments).
3. Lowest [vapor pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tungsten) of all metals, to prevent evaporation and thus blackening of the bulb (as pointed out by [Chemomechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/146039/chemomechanics) in the comments).
4. [Ductility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ductility) and high [tensile strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_tensile_strength), which makes it possible to shape it in thin filaments.

See also the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescent_light_bulb#Revolution_of_the_tungsten_filament,_inert_gas,_and_the_coiled_coil).

Comment: I think you mean *low* electrical resistivity (or high electrical *conductivity*).

Comment: @MarkH No, a high enough resistivity. But a different resistivity can be compensated for by using a different length and/or thickness of filament. But maybe filament made of copper would be too long or thin because its resistivity is too low.